# Same set of JS only work for one while others don't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am rather new to web building so this question might be quite easy for you to answer, but I have tried look-up for possible solutions and found no clue at all, here is my only hope.

I am trying to manipulate the effect in FB where you navigate posts with previous/next arrows and a close button. I made myself the buttons with image, and I want to script it so it will move on/back/close the content box when clicked without actually jumping from page to page.

I basically borrowed a fellow stackoverflower's (too lazy to find the page again, sorry :P) script to make it, and it works fine with chrome. The problem is, it doesn't work with my IE, and I have no clue why.

Here is the part that not working in IE (I think):
http://jsfiddle.net/ZfRW5/1/
(please ignore the image link)

In IE, I can click picture to access the overlay, but once the overlay is opened, the navigation buttons (next, previous and exit buttons) become un-clickable. 
It is utterly weird to me because I am using the same script for all these while apparently some works some doesn't.
This is the main script I use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('div').style.display='block';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block'">
<img src="../folder/picture.jpg" width="123" height="456" alt=""/></a>
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I am terribly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:fixed;` on children of `<a>` tags doesn't play nice in several browsers.

Try applying your `position:fixed` to the `<a>` itself, not the `<img>` within, and it should work fine.

Comment: I just tried putting the id in <a> itself than <img>, but it doesn't work still. Did I get you wrong?